# Oracle Apex prevent open new tab and new window

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to prevent users to open multiple tab and open multiple window on Oracle apex application, is there any way to handle it? the apex version is 20.2 and running over ORDS.

Comment: Do you want to "prevent users from opening multiple tabs and prevent them from opening multiple windows"? Or are you asking to "prevent users from opening multiple tabs and instead always open multiple windows"? And more importantly, why not just deal with the fact that users want to have multiple instances of your application open as it makes it more efficient for those users?

Comment: Hello, I want to prevent user to open multiple tab and they can't open new window too.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to prevent that; it's an OS or browser level function, not an application function.